# Django Admin Panel can't access specific items

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I've got a model of an article and everything works fine except when I change their status to draft - it disappears from Admin Django Panel. New articles are successfully added, but then don't show, the admin panel just can't access them. When I change the URL to force the admin panel to show me the details so I could edit it, I get a message that the article with the given ID doesn't exist. So basically every draft article gets lost. But I know they **have to exist** in my database because they show up on my article list view, but I can't go to detail view or draft view as I always get "No NewsModel matches the given query"

Django 2.0.5

models.py

```py
class NewsModel(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft','Draft'), 
        ('published','Published'),
    )

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    body = models.TextField()   
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)   
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="news/")
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse
        return reverse('main:news_details', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
        verbose_name = 'News'
        verbose_name_plural = 'News'
```

admin.py

```py
@admin.register(NewsModel)
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'game', 'news_type', 'author', 'finish', 'publish')
```

views.py

```py
def news_details(request, slug):
    news = get_object_or_404(NewsModel, slug=slug)
    news_aside = NewsModel.objects.filter(game=news.game).exclude(id=news.id)[:5]
    return render(request, 'news/news_details.html', {'news':news, 'news_aside':news_aside, 'section':'news'})

def news(request):
""" List of all news """
    news = NewsModel.objects.filter(status='published')[:3]

    latest = news[0]
    second = news[1]
    third = news[2]

    all_kind_news = NewsModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'news/news.html', {'news':news, 'section':'news', 'all':all_kind_news, 'latest':latest, 'second':second, 'third':third, 'section':'news'})

def drafts(request):
""" List of all drafts """
    news = NewsModel.objects.filter(status='draft')

    paginator = Paginator(news, 9)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    
    try:
        news = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        news = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        news = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    return render(request, 'news/news_list.html', {'news':news, 'section':'news', 'page':page})
```

urls.py (attaching just in case)

```py
path('news/', views.news, name='news'),
path('news/<slug>', views.news_details, name='news_details'),
path('news/drafts', views.drafts, name='drafts'),
```

News_details, drafts, and admin panel throw 404 error while trying to access drafts, but the news list doesn't have that problem. The weirdest thing is that also admin panel is affected.

Comment: hey, could it be becuase in your list_display items, you don not include the drafts, check this out -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: No, it's not that. I changed this now, restarted everything and still nothing.

Comment: have no idea but try with different browser and also try deleting all migrations and remigrate